# Azure ADF - Sink only changed columns

Tags: azure-data-factory, etl

I have a daily CSV export of a user list with the following changes:

- Lines (=Users) are added
- Data of Users (like Street names) can change

I would like to export only changed values and the user ID to json, but do not have an idea how to solve that.

I am already able to identify changed and added rows through a derived column that builds a sha1 checksum over all columns and filter only changed rows via „exists“.

But how would I do that on a column basis?

Sample Data:
**today.csv**

```
UserName,FirstName,LastName,Department
User01,John,Doe,Sales
```

**yesterday.csv**

```
UserName,FirstName,LastName,Department  
User01,John,Doe,Engineering
```

**Expected output:**
[{ "UserName": "User01", "Department": "Sales"}]

Thank you!

I tried to play with derived columns and joins, but everything returned a row, not individual values

Thank you for any ideas!
Best
Tobi

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this and provide some sample data? It's much easier to understand with some samples. Do you want to export changes to JSON because you are sending changes only to a web service?

Comment: Sure, the downstream logic needs to know what has changed to trigger changes in necessary downstream services only.  Sample Data:  **today.csv** 
 `UserName,FirstName,LastName,Department  User01,John,Doe,Sales`  **yesterday.csv**  
`UserName,FirstName,LastName,Department  
User01,John,Doe,Engineering`  
  
Expected output:  
[{ "UserName": "User01", "Department": "Sales"}]  
  
Thank you!

Comment: Q1: Does the output really need to be JSON? Personally I would simply do this inside a database using views and tables etc. If you want to do this in ADF and not use a database then you need to use mapping data flows which in turn need compute spin up times. Can you also extend your sample to show for example a user that is not changed, and a user that is _brand new_ . In order to do this kind of differential processing you either need to store the "current state" somewhere so you can compare to it, or the source system needs to explicitly tell you it's changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below is the sample data,

**today.csv**

```
UserName,FirstName,LastName,Department
User01,John,Doe,Sales
User03,Dileep,raj,Sales
```

**yesterday.csv**

```
UserName,FirstName,LastName,Department  
User01,John,Doe,Engineering
User02,Jay,adler,Engineering
User03,Dileep,raj,Engineering
```

I've done inner join to get the updated row results and used
`except()` function in derived column to get the updated columns.

Below is the data preview when join operation applied on `UserName`.

[image]

Here we got all columns of both files,`today.csv` and  `yesterday.csv`.
Then added `select` operation and made only one `UserName` column as below.

[image]

Then i've added derived column with new column as `Result`
and expression as below.

```
[concat('{ UserName:',TUserName,'}')] +  except([concat('{ FirstName:',TFirstName,'}'),concat('{ LastName:',TLastName,'}'),concat('{ Department:',TDepartment,'}')], [concat('{ FirstName:',YFirstName,'}'),concat('{ LastName:',YLastName,'}'),concat('{ Department:',{YDepartment },'}')])
```

This expression removes duplicates in arrays.
You can add columns whichever you need in this expression.

[image]

At last selected the `Result` column using select operation and added sink to adls gen2 storage as json.

[image]

And this is the result in storage.

[image]

Comment: Woooow!, thank you so much for this detailled how to :-) Will check this tomorrow :-)